# Is File#print atomic when given multiple arguments?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

For C-based implementations of ruby 1.8 and ruby 1.9, is `File#print` atomic when it is given multiple arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examining it empirically, the answer's no.

```
10.times do
  Thread.new do
    print "foo", "\n"
  end
end
```

gives (in ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [universal-darwin10.0])

```
foofoofoo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
```

Don't know where you can look up what is atomic and what isn't atomic, though.